# SQL Server - find nth occurrence in a string

Tags: sql-server

I have a table column that contains values such as `abc_1_2_3_4.gif` or `zzz_12_3_3_45.gif` etc.

**I want to find the index of each underscore** _ in the above values. There will only ever be four underscores but given that they can be in any position in the string, how can I achieve this?

I've tried the [substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) and [charindex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) function, but I can only reliably get hold of the first one. Any ideas?

Comment: a cursor is a solution for you?

Comment: @adrianos - how big a data set are you expecting?  What version of SQL server?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

One way (2k8);

```
select 'abc_1_2_3_4.gif  ' as img into #T
insert #T values ('zzz_12_3_3_45.gif')

;with T as (
    select 0 as row, charindex('_', img) pos, img from #T
    union all
    select pos + 1, charindex('_', img, pos + 1), img
    from T
    where pos > 0
)
select 
    img, pos 
from T 
where pos > 0   
order by img, pos

>>>>

img                 pos
abc_1_2_3_4.gif     4
abc_1_2_3_4.gif     6
abc_1_2_3_4.gif     8
abc_1_2_3_4.gif     10
zzz_12_3_3_45.gif   4
zzz_12_3_3_45.gif   7
zzz_12_3_3_45.gif   9
zzz_12_3_3_45.gif   11
```

**Update**

```
;with T(img, starts, pos) as (
    select img, 1, charindex('_', img) from #t
    union all
    select img, pos + 1, charindex('_', img, pos + 1)
    from t
    where pos > 0
)
select 
    *, substring(img, starts, case when pos > 0 then pos - starts else len(img) end) token
from T
order by img, starts

>>>

img                 starts  pos     token
abc_1_2_3_4.gif     1       4       abc
abc_1_2_3_4.gif     5       6       1
abc_1_2_3_4.gif     7       8       2
abc_1_2_3_4.gif     9       10      3
abc_1_2_3_4.gif     11      0       4.gif  
zzz_12_3_3_45.gif   1       4       zzz
zzz_12_3_3_45.gif   5       7       12
zzz_12_3_3_45.gif   8       9       3
zzz_12_3_3_45.gif   10      11      3
zzz_12_3_3_45.gif   12      0       45.gif
```

Comment: hmmm, Invalid object name '#t'.

Comment: Its from my test data @ the top `... into #T` substitute the correct object name

Comment: really sorry, couldn't get it to work this way - sqlserver is not my strong suit! +1 in thanks though.

Comment: Is there a way to use this with an NVARCHAR(MAX) or TEXT column? So far it seems if no length is defined it will fail with "Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column X"

Comment: For `NVARCHAR(MAX)` try changing `select img, 1, charindex('_', img) from #t` to `select img, cast(1 as bigint), charindex('_', img) from #t`

Answer (score 53):

You can use the same function inside for the position `+1`

```
charindex('_', [TEXT], (charindex('_', [TEXT], 1))+1)
```

in where `+1` is the nth time you will want to find.

Comment: there is a bug in this method. this method only works if you are sure you have `n` occurrence.
if you try to find 3rd occurrence and you have 1 occurrence 
in first `charindex` you get `x` but then when you search `x+1' you get 0 
but now you search from 1 and again you get the x.
so if you have just one occurrence you get its location or 1 as output.

Comment: This will find the second underscore but `charindex('_', [TEXT], (charindex('_', [TEXT], 1))+2)` will not find the third, which is what I think you're implying. Instead `charindex('_', [TEXT], (charindex('_', [TEXT], 1))+charindex('_', [TEXT], (charindex('_', [TEXT], 1))+1))` will find the third underscore.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `CHARINDEX` and specify the starting location:

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(32) = 'MS-SQL-Server';

SELECT 
  STUFF(STUFF(@x,3 , 0, '/'), 8, 0, '/') InsertString
  ,CHARINDEX('-',LTRIM(RTRIM(@x))) FirstIndexOf
  ,CHARINDEX('-',LTRIM(RTRIM(@x)), (CHARINDEX('-', LTRIM(RTRIM(@x)) )+1)) SecondIndexOf
  ,CHARINDEX('-',@x,CHARINDEX('-',@x, (CHARINDEX('-',@x)+1))+1) ThirdIndexOf
  ,CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(LTRIM(RTRIM(@x)))) LastIndexOf;
GO
```

Answer (score 10):

```
DECLARE @str AS VARCHAR(100)
SET @str='1,2  , 3,   4,   5,6'
SELECT COALESCE(LTRIM(CAST(('<X>'+REPLACE(@str,',' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML).value('(/X)[1]', 'varchar(128)')), ''),
       COALESCE(LTRIM(CAST(('<X>'+REPLACE(@str,',' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML).value('(/X)[2]', 'varchar(128)')), ''),
       COALESCE(LTRIM(CAST(('<X>'+REPLACE(@str,',' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML).value('(/X)[3]', 'varchar(128)')), ''),
       COALESCE(LTRIM(CAST(('<X>'+REPLACE(@str,',' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML).value('(/X)[4]', 'varchar(128)')), ''),
       COALESCE(LTRIM(CAST(('<X>'+REPLACE(@str,',' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML).value('(/X)[5]', 'varchar(128)')), ''),
       COALESCE(LTRIM(CAST(('<X>'+REPLACE(@str,',' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML).value('(/X)[6]', 'varchar(128)')), ''),
       COALESCE(LTRIM(CAST(('<X>'+REPLACE(@str,',' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML).value('(/X)[7]', 'varchar(128)')), ''),
       COALESCE(LTRIM(CAST(('<X>'+REPLACE(@str,',' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML).value('(/X)[8]', 'varchar(128)')), ''),
       COALESCE(LTRIM(CAST(('<X>'+REPLACE(@str,',' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML).value('(/X)[9]', 'varchar(128)')), '')
```

Comment: thanks. needed just 3 items in the list to be separated into a table and all other solutions are too looooooooooong:)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following `function` to `split the values` by a `delimiter`. It'll `return a table` and to find the nth occurrence just make a `select` on it! Or change it a little for it to `return` what you need instead of the `table`.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split
(
    @RowData nvarchar(2000),
    @SplitOn nvarchar(5)
)  
RETURNS @RtnValue table 
(
    Id int identity(1,1),
    Data nvarchar(100)
) 
AS  
BEGIN 
    Declare @Cnt int
    Set @Cnt = 1

    While (Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)>0)
    Begin
        Insert Into @RtnValue (data)
        Select 
            Data = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@RowData,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)-1)))

        Set @RowData = Substring(@RowData,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)+1,len(@RowData))
        Set @Cnt = @Cnt + 1
    End

    Insert Into @RtnValue (data)
    Select Data = ltrim(rtrim(@RowData))

    Return
END
```

Comment: Not a speed demon function, but very useful for these one off queries I seem to have to constantly write!  Works great!

Comment: @Limey if it happens many times try to use another solution. Cursors are not the way to go in sql server ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can [look for the four underscore in this way](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/123154/):

```
create table #test
( t varchar(50) );

insert into #test values 
( 'abc_1_2_3_4.gif'),
('zzz_12_3_3_45.gif');

declare @t varchar(50);
declare @t_aux varchar(50);
declare @t1 int;
declare @t2 int;
declare @t3 int;
declare @t4 int;

DECLARE t_cursor CURSOR
    FOR SELECT t FROM #test
OPEN t_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM t_cursor into @t;​
set @t1 = charindex( '_', @t )
set @t2 = charindex( '_', @t , @t1+1)
set @t3 = charindex( '_', @t , @t2+1)
set @t4 = charindex( '_', @t , @t3+1)

select @t1, @t2, t3, t4

--do a loop to iterate over all table
```

you can test it here.

Or in this simple way:

```
select 
  charindex( '_', t ) as first,
  charindex( '_', t, charindex( '_', t ) + 1 ) as second,
  ...
from 
  #test
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try peeling the variable/array, assuming distinctness in your list

```
declare @array table   ----table of values
(
    id int identity(1,1)
    ,value nvarchar(max)
)
DECLARE @VALUE NVARCHAR(MAX)='val1_val2_val3_val4_val5_val6_val7'----string array
DECLARE @CURVAL NVARCHAR(MAX)     ---current value
DECLARE @DELIM NVARCHAR(1)='_'    ---delimiter
DECLARE @BREAKPT INT              ---current index of the delimiter 

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT @VALUE)  
    BEGIN
        SET @BREAKPT=CHARINDEX(@DELIM,@VALUE)   ---set the current index
        ---
        If @BREAKPT<> 0                          ---index at 0 breaks the loop
            begin
                SET @CURVAL=SUBSTRING(@VALUE,1,@BREAKPT-1)                  ---current value
                set @VALUE=REPLACE(@VALUE,SUBSTRING(@VALUE,1,@BREAKPT),'')  ---current value and delimiter, replace
                insert into @array(value)                                   ---insert data 
                select @CURVAL
            end
        else
            begin
                SET @CURVAL=@VALUE                                          ---current value now last value
                insert into @array(value)                                   ---insert data
                select @CURVAL
                break                                                       ---break loop
            end
    end

select * from @array    ---find nth occurance given the id
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple sample to do this with xml conversion:

```
SELECT 'A|B|C' AS text
 , concat('<x>', REPLACE('A|B|C', '|', '</x><x>'), '</x>') AS xml
 , cast(concat('<x>', REPLACE('A|B|C', '|', '</x><x>'), '</x>') as xml).query('/x[2]') AS tag
 , cast(concat('<x>', REPLACE('A|B|C', '|', '</x><x>'), '</x>') as xml).value('/x[3]',     
   'varchar(max)') AS char; -- or varchar({your size})
```

or from CTE/Table like:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 'A|B|C' AS text
)
SELECT concat('<x>', REPLACE(text, '|', '</x><x>'), '</x>') AS xml
 , cast(concat('<x>', REPLACE(text, '|', '</x><x>'), '</x>') as xml).query('/x[2]') AS tag
 , cast(concat('<x>', REPLACE(text, '|', '</x><x>'), '</x>') as xml).value('/x[2]',     
   'varchar') AS char
FROM Data
```

Returns

| xml | tag | char |
| --- | --- | --- |
| <x>A</x><x>B</x><x>C</x> | <x>B</x> | B |

And here a translation for your sample:

```
SELECT gifname
      ,cast(concat('<x>', REPLACE(gifname, '_', '</x><x>'), '</x>') as xml).query('/x[2]') as xmlelement
     , cast(concat('<x>', REPLACE(gifname, '_', '</x><x>'), '</x>') as xml).value('/x[2]', 'varchar(10)') as result
    FROM (
      SELECT 'abc_1_2_3_4.gif' as gifname
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'zzz_12_3_3_45.gif'
    ) tmp
```

Comment: Best solution ever! Thanks for posting that. You are a master of XML and string manipulation.

Comment: There are two issues with this answer: 1) The first example select tag 2, but value 3. This is confusing. 2) If you test with `'AA|BB|CC'`, you'll get value `'C'`, rather than `'CC'`. To fix this, replace the last cast by `cast(...,'varchar(max)')`

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @LEN INT
DECLARE @VAR VARCHAR(20)
SET @VAR = 'HELLO WORLD'
SET @LEN = LEN(@VAR)
--SELECT @LEN
SELECT PATINDEX('%O%',SUBSTRING(@VAR,PATINDEX('%O%' ,@VAR) +  1 ,PATINDEX('%O%',@VAR) + 1)) + PATINDEX('%O%',@VAR)
```

Comment: It would be worth adding an explanation with your code. Code dumps are often downvoted and may be removed. See [answer].

Comment: it is for second occurence of character in string

Comment: There is a little edit button under your answer. Select that and add in the explanation in there. Comments may get removed you see and I wouldn't want that to happen.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

My SQL supports the function of a substring_Index where it will return the postion of a value in a string for the n occurance.  A similar User defined function could be written to achieve this.  Example in the [link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic806552-338-1.aspx)

Alternatively you could use charindex function call it x times to report the location of each _ given a starting postion +1 of the previously found instance. until a 0 is found

Edit: NM Charindex is the correct function

Comment: I like substring_index in MySQL which does this with one query. Not sure why MS thinks this can't be implemented in SQL Server is beyond me. It doesn't take a rocket scientist to implement something like that!

Answer (score 1):

I did this creating several separate custom functions, one for each position of the searched character i.e. 2nd, 3rd:

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnCHARPOS2]
    (@SEARCHCHAR VARCHAR(255),
    @SEARCHSTRING VARCHAR(255))
    RETURNS INT
    AS
    BEGIN
    RETURN       CHARINDEX(@SEARCHCHAR,@SEARCHSTRING(CHARINDEX(@SEARCHCHAR,@SEARCHSTRING,0)+1));

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnCHARPOS3]
(@SEARCHCHAR VARCHAR(255),
@SEARCHSTRING VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
 RETURN CHARINDEX(@SEARCHCHAR,@SEARCHSTRING,    (CHARINDEX(@SEARCHCHAR,@SEARCHSTRING,    (CHARINDEX(@SEARCHCHAR,@SEARCHSTRING,0)+1)))+1);
```

You can then pass in as a parameter the character you are searching for and the string you are searching in:

So if you were searching for 'f' and wanted to know position of 1st 3 occurences:

```
select 
database.dbo.fnCHARPOS2('f',tablename.columnname),
database.dbo.fnCHARPOS3('f',tablename.columnname)
from tablename
```

It worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I decided to use a recursive function because for me it was easier to follow the logic.  Note that SQL Server has a default function recursion limit of 32, so this is only good for smaller workloads.

```
create function dbo._charindex_nth (
  @FindThis varchar(8000),
  @InThis varchar(max),
  @StartFrom int,
  @NthOccurence tinyint
)
returns bigint
as
begin
  /*
  Recursive helper used by dbo.charindex_nth to return the position of the nth occurance of @FindThis in @InThis

  Who   When    What
  PJR   160421  Initial   
  */

  declare @Pos bigint

  if isnull(@NthOccurence, 0) <= 0 or isnull(@StartFrom, 0) <= 0
  begin
    select @Pos = 0
  end else begin
    if @NthOccurence = 1
    begin
      select @Pos = charindex(@FindThis, @InThis, @StartFrom)
    end else begin
      select @Pos = dbo._charindex_nth(@FindThis, @InThis, nullif(charindex(@FindThis, @InThis, @StartFrom), 0) + 1, @NthOccurence - 1)
    end
  end

  return @Pos
end

create function dbo.charindex_nth (
  @FindThis varchar(8000),
  @InThis varchar(max),
  @NthOccurence tinyint
)
returns bigint
as
begin
  /*
  Returns the position of the nth occurance of @FindThis in @InThis

  Who   When    What
  PJR   160421  Initial   
  */

  return dbo._charindex_nth(@FindThis, @InThis, 1, @NthOccurence)
end

declare @val varchar(max) = 'zzz_12_3_3_45.gif'

select dbo.charindex_nth('_', @val, 1) Underscore1
  , dbo.charindex_nth('_', @val, 2) Underscore2
  , dbo.charindex_nth('_', @val, 3) Underscore3
  , dbo.charindex_nth('_', @val, 4) Underscore4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE(pic_name VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @T VALUES ('abc_1_2_3_4.gif'),('zzz_12_3_3_45.gif');

SELECT A.pic_name, P1.D, P2.D, P3.D, P4.D 
FROM @T A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT NULLIF(CHARINDEX('_', A.pic_name),0) AS D)  P1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT NULLIF(CHARINDEX('_', A.pic_name, P1.D+1), 0) AS D)  P2
CROSS APPLY (SELECT NULLIF(CHARINDEX('_', A.pic_name, P2.D+1),0) AS D)  P3
CROSS APPLY (SELECT NULLIF(CHARINDEX('_', A.pic_name, P3.D+1),0) AS D)  P4
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used a function to grab the "nth" element from a delimited string field with great success. Like mentioned above, it's not a "fast" way of dealing with things but it sure as heck is convenient.

```
create function GetArrayIndex(@delimited nvarchar(max), @index int,  @delimiter nvarchar(100) = ',')  returns nvarchar(max)  
as    
begin     
 declare @xml xml, @result nvarchar(max)  
 set @xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@delimited, @delimiter,'</r><r>') + '</r></root>'  
 select @result = r.value('.','varchar(max)')   
 from @xml.nodes('//root/r[sql:variable("@index")]') as records(r)  

 return @result   
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I was toying with a faster way to do this than simply iterating through the string.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [ssf_GetNthSeparatorPosition] ( @TargetString VARCHAR(MAX)
                                              , @Sep VARCHAR(25)
                                              , @n INTEGER )
RETURNS INTEGER
/****************************************************************************************
--#############################################################################
-- Returns the position of the Nth Charactor sequence
--                                     1234567890123456789
-- Declare @thatString varchar(max) = 'hi,there,jay,yo'
  Select dbo.ssf_GetNthSeparatorPosition(@thatString, ',', 3) --would return 13
--############################################################################ 


****************************************************************************************/
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Retval INTEGER = 0
        DECLARE @CurPos INTEGER = 0
        DECLARE @LenSep INTEGER = LEN(@Sep)

        SELECT @CurPos = CHARINDEX(@Sep, @TargetString)

        IF ISNULL(@LenSep, 0) > 0
            AND @CurPos > 0
            BEGIN

               SELECT @CurPos = 0
              ;with lv0 AS (SELECT 0 g UNION ALL SELECT 0)
                            ,lv1 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv0 a CROSS JOIN lv0 b) -- 4
                            ,lv2 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv1 a CROSS JOIN lv1 b) -- 16
                            ,lv3 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv2 a CROSS JOIN lv2 b) -- 256
                            ,lv4 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv3 a CROSS JOIN lv3 b) -- 65,536
                            ,lv5 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv4 a CROSS JOIN lv4 b) -- 4,294,967,296
                            ,Tally (n) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM lv5),
                        results
                          AS ( SELECT n - LEN(@Sep) AS Nth
                                ,   row_number() OVER ( ORDER BY n ) - 1 AS Position
                                FROM Tally t
                                WHERE n BETWEEN 1
                                        AND     DATALENGTH(@TargetString) + DATALENGTH(@Sep)
                                    AND SUBSTRING(@Sep + @TargetString, n, LEN(@Sep)) = @Sep)
                    SELECT @CurPos = Nth
                        FROM results
                        WHERE results.Position = @n


            END
        RETURN @CurPos

    END

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @a nvarchar(50)='Enter Your string '
declare @character char='e'
declare @nthoccurence int = 2
declare @i int = 1
declare @j int =0
declare @count int = len(@a)-len(replace(@a,@character,''))

if(@count >= @nthoccurence)
begin
        while (@I <= @nthoccurence)
        begin
            set @j= CHARINDEX(@character,@a,@j+1)
            set @i= @i+1
        end
        print @j
end
else
    Print 'you have only '+convert(nvarchar ,@count)+' occurrences of '+@character
end
```

Comment: Please explain your code and what makes it different from the other answered solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(32) = 'MS-SQL-Server';

SELECT 
SUBSTRING(@x,0,CHARINDEX('-',LTRIM(RTRIM(@x)))) A,
SUBSTRING(@x,CHARINDEX('-',LTRIM(RTRIM(@x)))+1,CHARINDEX('-' 
,LTRIM(RTRIM(@x)))) B,
SUBSTRING(@x,CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(LTRIM(RTRIM(@x))))+1,LEN(@x)-1) C


A   B   C
MS  SQL Server
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Alex K's reply One way (2k8), I have created a script for a Token Function for the SQL Server for returning a specific token from a string.
I needed this for refacturing a SSIS-package to T-SQL without having to implement Alex' solution a number of times manually.
My function has one disadvantage: It returns the token value as a table (one column, one row) instead of as a varchar value. If anyone has a solution for this, please let me know.

```
DROP FUNCTION [RDW].[token]
GO

create function [RDW].[token] (@string varchar(8000), @split varchar(50), @returnIndex int) 
returns table  
as 
    return with T(img, starts, pos, [index]) as ( 
        select @string, 1, charindex(@split, @string), 0 
        union all 
        select @string, pos + 1, charindex(@split, @string, pos + 1), [index]+1 
        from t 
        where pos > 0
    )
    select substring(img, starts, case when pos > 0 then pos - starts else len(img) end) token
    from T
    where [index] = @returnIndex 
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CHARINDEX2] (
    @expressionToFind VARCHAR(MAX),
    @expressionToSearch VARCHAR(MAX),
    @occurrenceIndex INT,
    @startLocation INT = 0
)
RETURNS INT
AS BEGIN

IF @occurrenceIndex < 1 BEGIN
    RETURN CAST('The argument @occurrenceIndex must be a positive integer.' AS INT)
END

IF @startLocation < 0 BEGIN
    RETURN CAST('The argument @startLocation must be a non negative integer.' AS INT)
END

DECLARE @returnIndex INT

SET @returnIndex = CHARINDEX(@expressionToFind, @expressionToSearch, @startLocation)

IF (@occurrenceIndex = 1) BEGIN
    RETURN @returnIndex
END

DECLARE @target_length INT
SET @target_length = LEN(@expressionToFind)
SET @occurrenceIndex += -1

WHILE (@occurrenceIndex > 0 AND @returnIndex > 0) BEGIN
    SET @returnIndex = CHARINDEX(@expressionToFind, @expressionToSearch, @returnIndex + @target_length);
    SET @occurrenceIndex += -1
END

RETURN @returnIndex

END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [pub].[SplitString] 
(   @StringToSplit nvarchar(MAX),
    @Delimiter as nvarchar(10) 
)

-- Example of use:
-- select * from [pub].[SplitString] ('one;two;three;;for & six;', ';')

RETURNS
    @returnList TABLE ([Item] [nvarchar] (4000), [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @xml as xml

    SET @xml = 
        cast
        (   ('<X>' + replace(replace(@StringToSplit, @Delimiter ,'</X><X>'),'&','&amp;') + '</X>'
            ) as xml
        )

    INSERT INTO @returnList([Item])
    SELECT 
        N.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as [Item] 
    FROM 
        @xml.nodes('X') as T(N)

    RETURN
END
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not directly answer the question, but as I have found this while looking for a solution for extracting multiple values from a single string, with a specific delimiter, I post it anyway in case it could help someone.

SQL Server ships with the function PARSENAME that can extract up to 4 elements in a dot separated string, from the right :

```
SELECT PARSENAME('1234.5437.43278.532', 2) as third_element
--43278
```

You could use this function to retrieve the 2nd to the 5th element of the file name, by selecting from the second element to the end of the filename, without the extension.

Note that the code to remove the file extension (the 4th position from the right) is hardcoded here, so it's better to change it if you have some mix with .jpg and .jpeg file extensions for instance.

```sql
DECLARE @t TABLE (
  c_filename VARCHAR(1000)
) INSERT @t 
values 
  ('abc_1_2_3_4.gif'), 
  ('abcdefgh_1231_78432_398389_12144.png') 
SELECT 
  LEFT(
    c_filename, 
    CHARINDEX('_', c_filename) -1
  ) as first_element, 
  PARSENAME(
    REPLACE(
      /* PARSENAME only works with 4 elements */
      /* we remove :
      - the 1st element
      - and the file extension */
      SUBSTRING( 
        c_filename, 
        CHARINDEX('_', c_filename) + 1, 
        LEN(c_filename) - CHARINDEX('_', c_filename) -4
      ), 
      '_', 
      '.'
    ), 
    4 -- change this to get the nth element
  ) as second_element, 
  PARSENAME(
    REPLACE(
      SUBSTRING(
        c_filename, 
        CHARINDEX('_', c_filename) + 1, 
        LEN(c_filename) - CHARINDEX('_', c_filename) -4
      ), 
      '_', 
      '.'
    ), 
    3
  ) as third_element, 
  PARSENAME(
    REPLACE(
      SUBSTRING(
        c_filename, 
        CHARINDEX('_', c_filename) + 1, 
        LEN(c_filename) - CHARINDEX('_', c_filename) -4
      ), 
      '_', 
      '.'
    ), 
    2
  ) as fourth_element, 
  PARSENAME(
    REPLACE(
      SUBSTRING(
        c_filename, 
        CHARINDEX('_', c_filename) + 1, 
        LEN(c_filename) - CHARINDEX('_', c_filename) -4
      ), 
      '_', 
      '.'
    ), 
    1
  ) as fifth_element 
FROM 
  @t
```

```
+---------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+
| first_element | second_element | third_element | fourth_element | fifth_element |
+---------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+
| abc           | 1              |             2 |              3 |             4 |
| abcdefghijkl  | 12qwerty31     |      78891432 |      398977389 |    1212345344 |
+---------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+
```