# SELECT from 3rd comma in string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following string:

```
bzip2,1,668,sometext,foo,bar
```

How can I SELECT only `sometext,foo,bar`? The length of the string preceding the 3rd comma may differ and there may be commas within `sometext,foo,bar`.

I'd like this in as concise code as possible, i.e. preferably 1 line of code, no loops. But feel free to post any solution you think of.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This has absolutely *zero* to do with the question.

Comment: Perhaps this might give you a start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726111/sql-server-find-nth-occurrence-in-a-string

Comment: Will there always be exactly 3 commas (4 "elements") ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It isn't comma seperated values. It is a BZ compressed string. Each row has a different string. Please just trust the question here, it is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Bridge This is what I meant with "there may be commas within `sometext`". There might be 100 commas.

Comment: I've edited the question so we stop getting answers that ignore the fact that there may be commas in the remainder of the string. In the future please make this case more obvious up front.

Comment: Since @a_horse_with_no_name's post now has 8 upvotes, I'll explain a little why I have something like this in a database. An external application stores BZ2-compressed rich-text notes in this column. It automatically adds 'bzip2,1,668,' to the start of every string (the numbers may differ each time). In order to decompress the string, I need to remove this prefix, otherwise BZDecompress returns that it is not a valid BZ string. Nothing to do with data storage; and certainly not something that can be normalised.

Comment: You should have added that explanation right from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out something that works:

```
declare @v varchar(max) = 'bzip2,1,668,sometext'
select substring(@v, CHARINDEX(',', @v, CHARINDEX(',', @v, CHARINDEX(',', @v)+1)+1)+1, len(@v))
```

Comment: I would recommend you accept @Joe answer then, as that's exactly the same solution he provided 3 minutes ago.

Comment: @Mike Yes, I figured this out a little before @Joe posted his answer. His is slightly different though, it has more `1`'s and `@v`'s

Comment: As a rule of thumb, the OP should not post answers to his own question within several minutes of posting.

Comment: @DenisValeev Firstly, anyone can post an answer immediately, *whilst* posting their question. Secondly, I'd been searching for a solution for half an hour. By chance I thought of the solution a few minutes after posting the question. You've lost me; at what point is it unacceptable to post an answer? Especially when it's the best answer of the bunch...

Comment: Just noticed that @Joe's answer also includes the double the calls to `CHARINDEX()`

Answer (score 8):

try this:

Do a substring from 3rd comma to the end of the string.. To find the 3 commas , I am using charindex() function 3 times

```
  declare @str varchar(50)='bzip2,1,668,some,text'

  select substring(@str,
  CHARINDEX(',',@str,CHARINDEX(',',@str,CHARINDEX(',',@str,1)+1)+1)+1,
  LEN(@str)-CHARINDEX(',',@str,CHARINDEX(',',@str,CHARINDEX(',',@str,1)+1)+1))
```

**result**:

```
some,text
```

Comment: Just to comment here, since I see this is still getting more upvotes... it uses double the amount of `CHARINDEX`s as my answer. A better solution is: `declare @v varchar(max) = 'bzip2,1,668,sometext'
select substring(@v, CHARINDEX(',', @v, CHARINDEX(',', @v, CHARINDEX(',', @v)+1)+1)+1, len(@v))` (as I posted as my answer).

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```
declare @input varchar(max) = 'bzip2,1,668,s,o,m,e,t,e,x,t,f,o,o,b,a,r'
--declare @input varchar(max) = 'bzip2,,'
declare @thirdCommaPosition int = nullif(charindex(',', @input, nullif(charindex(',', @input, nullif(charindex(',', @input, 1),0)+1),0)+1 ),0)
select stuff(@input, 1, @thirdCommaPosition, '')
```

Output:

```
s,o,m,e,t,e,x,t,f,o,o,b,a,r
```

**Edit**

Added nullif's to the third comma calculation part, without them it's possible to get inconsistent results.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another idea

```
DECLARE @xml AS XML,@str AS VARCHAR(50)
    SET @str='bzip2,1,668,sometext,foo,bar'

    SET @xml = CAST(('<X>'+REPLACE(@str,',' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML)


        SELECT FinalResult = STUFF(@str,1,SUM(Length)+3,' ' ) FROM (SELECT 
                                Rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) 
                                ,N.value('.', 'varchar(10)') as value
                                ,Length = LEN(N.value('.', 'varchar(10)'))  
                            FROM @xml.nodes('X') as T(N))X 
        WHERE X.Rn<=3
```

**Result**

```
 sometext,foo,bar
```

Comment: Order is not guaranteed here, so you could potentially get the split elements of the string back in a different order when the post-stuff contains commas.

Comment: I am generating it (Row Number) in a sequential way.So how will the order change?

Comment: It might not, but that's not the point, it's not guaranteed! How is it sequential? Your inner order by purposely makes the order arbitrary, and the outer query doesn't use order by at all!