# How to extract a string inside others string in sql in a table?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, substring, varchar

I have a table, a column has something as it

> EXECUTE grabaped '2013-11-19' , '1',921,45986,**'  639  780  988 1018
>   1076 1868 2141'  ,'    2    1    4    1    1    1    1'**,7,1,0,1,40,131

I want to get the bold text, but

> EXECUTE grabaped '2013-11-19' , '1',921,45986, can to have N characteres

But always it is going to have 4 commas and
always it is going to have 2 varchar and 2 int.

I have the column in table.

[image]

Comment: just look into the string functions available to you... this should be fairly straightforward.  what database are you using?

Comment: As long as the varchars themselves don't contain commas, then use substring() to extract the string and use charindex() (once for each comma) to calculate the parameters for substring().

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726111/sql-server-find-nth-occurrence-in-a-string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387559/select-from-3rd-comma-in-string?lq=1

Comment: first, find the position of the 4th comma.  do a substring from that +1 to the end.  in that substring, find the occurrence of the _second_ comma.  do a substring from the start to the position of that (now) _second_ comma.

Comment: or write a function.  which would be easier.  and just split the data up... you could even pass in a parameter that determines what index or indices get returned. you could either return the value or return a table format.  it should only take 15-45 minutes depending on skills.