# SQL group by part of string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following data in my table:

```
URL         TIME    DATE
--------------------------------------
/x          11      2013-08-01
/x          11      2013-08-01
/pl/        11      2013-08-01
/pl/        11      2013-08-03
/pl/XXX/    11      2013-08-01
/pl/XXX/    11      2013-08-04
/pl/XXX/1   11      2013-08-01
/pl/XXX/2   11      2013-08-01
/pl/YYY/    11      2013-08-01
/pl/YYY/1   11      2013-08-01
/pl/YYY/2   11      2013-08-04
/pl/YYY/3   11      2013-08-04
```

Is there a way to group by URL up to third  slash (`/`) in SQL Server? Unfortunately there exists record which contains less than three.

Comment: You should read that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726111/sql-server-find-nth-occurrence-in-a-string

Comment: Is this one, two or three slashes: `pl/XXX`? I ask because it might be  the same path as `/pl/XXX/`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter all data starts with slash so it is not a problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One trick to count the number of slashes in a string is:

```
len(url) - len(replace(url,'/',''))
```

You can then use `charindex` three times to find the position of the third slash:

```
select  BeforeThirdSlash
,       max([date])
from    (
        select  case 
                when len(url) - len(replace(url,'/','')) < 3 then url
                else substring(url, 1, charindex('/', url, charindex('/', 
                         url, charindex('/', url)+1)+1)-1)
                end as BeforeThirdSlash
        ,       *
        from    @t
        ) as SubQueryAlias
group by
        BeforeThirdSlash
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/588d4/1/0)

Answer (score 4):

A simple expression that lets you grab the substring up to the third `'/'` character is as follows:

```
case
    when patindex('%/%/%/%', url) = 0 then url
    else left(url,charindex('/',url,charindex('/',url,charindex('/',url)+1)+1))
end
```

The `patindex` checks that there are at least three slashes; the `left` extracts the substring up to and including the third one.

With this expression in hand, writing a `group by` is simple:

```
SELECT
    url3, max(tm), max(dt)
FROM (
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN patindex('%/%/%/%', url) = 0 THEN url
            ELSE left(url,charindex('/',url,charindex('/',url,charindex('/',url)+1)+1))
        END AS url3
    ,   tm
    ,   dt
    FROM test
) x
GROUP BY url3
```

[Demo on SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7abb3c/1).

Answer (score 3):

You could find the position of each position of `/` and trim to the `MAX(position)` - presuming the third `/` is the last `/` as per the data.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE ( u VARCHAR(255), t INT, d DATE)

INSERT INTO @tbl (u, t, d) VALUES
('/x',          11,      '2013-08-01'),
('/x',          11,      '2013-08-01'),
('/pl/',        11,      '2013-08-01'),
('/pl/',        11,      '2013-08-03'),
('/pl/XXX/',    11,      '2013-08-01'),
('/pl/XXX/',    11,      '2013-08-04'),
('/pl/XXX/1',   11,      '2013-08-01'),
('/pl/XXX/2',   11,      '2013-08-01'),
('/pl/YYY/',    11,      '2013-08-01'),
('/pl/YYY/1',   11,      '2013-08-01'),
('/pl/YYY/2',   11,      '2013-08-04'),
('/pl/YYY/3',   11,      '2013-08-04')

;WITH split AS (
    SELECT u, 1 s, CHARINDEX('/', u) p
    FROM @tbl
    UNION ALL
    SELECT u, p + 1, CHARINDEX('/', u, p + 1)
    FROM split
)

SELECT LEFT(t.u, split.i), MAX(t.t), MAX(t.d)
FROM @tbl t
JOIN (
    SELECT u, MAX(p) i 
    FROM split
    GROUP BY u
) split ON split.u = t.u
GROUP BY LEFT(t.u, split.i)
```

With a slight adjustment to the cte you can control the occurences

```
DECLARE @n INT = 3    -- 'nth occurence'

;WITH split AS (
    SELECT u, CHARINDEX('/', u) i, 1 r
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT u
        FROM @tbl
    ) t
    WHERE CHARINDEX('/', u) > 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT u, CHARINDEX('/', u, i + 1), r + 1
    FROM split
    WHERE r < @n
    AND CHARINDEX('/', u, i + 1) > 0
)

SELECT LEFT(t.u, split.i) u, MAX(t.t) t , MAX(t.d) d
FROM @tbl t
JOIN split ON split.u = t.u
GROUP BY LEFT(t.u, split.i)
```

[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f2537/12)