# Select every occurrence of substring in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a Post table:

```
PostID    PostHTML
===
1         '<p>Hello world! <img height=400 src="hello-world.jpg" height=600></p>'
2         'Bowties <img src="bowtie.gif" /> are cool. <img src="smiley.gif" />'
3         '<TABLE CELLSPACING=0 BORDER=0 CELLPADDING=0><TR><TD><B><FONT FACE="Arial"><P ALIGN="CENTER"><IMG SRC="FOO.GIF"></P></FONT></B></TD><TD><B><FONT FACE="Arial"><P ALIGN="CENTER"><IMG SRC="BAR.GIF"></P></FONT></B></TD><TD><B><FONT FACE="Arial"><P ALIGN="CENTER"><IMG SRC="INTERNET-CIRCA-1997.GIF"></P></FONT></B></TD></TR></TABLE>'
4         '<B><FONT FACE="Arial"><P>Did I mention this data is hideous?</P></B><P>&nbsp;</P></FONT>'
```

I need to select the `src` attribute of every image in this table. So far I can get the first occurrence in each row:

```
select substring(
    posthtml,
    charindex('src="', posthtml),
    charindex('"', posthtml, charindex('src="', posthtml) + 5) - charindex('src="', posthtml) + 1
) from post
```

This results in:

```
src="hello-world.jpg"
src="bowtie.gif"
SRC="FOO.GIF"
```

What I want is this:

```
src="hello-world.jpg"
src="bowtie.gif"
src="smiley.gif"
SRC="FOO.GIF"
SRC="BAR.GIF"
SRC="INTERNET-CIRCA-1997.GIF"
```

How do I get all occurrences in every row?

Comment: Do you want to fetch the row which has the string 'src' ????

Comment: @Pradeep I updated the question to show the data I'm getting and the data I'd like.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the ability to run the "coss apply" functionality in SQL server. Create a function that decomposes the value in to a result table, then join that result table using the ['cross apply'](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) concept in a join condition.

Doing this would result in a function that produces a table output, with the input of your String, it would run a 'cursor' over the string, and then add values to the result table. If you call the function "SearchSRC", it would look somethin glike:

```
select capply.Sources
from mytable
     cross apply SearchSrc(mytable.PostHTML) as capply
```

It can be relatively complicated, but the documentation has an example too.

I put together an [**SQLFiddle demonstrating this solution here**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6d4c9/3/0) (Note that an early version of my code on SQLFiddle produced an infinite loop, and now it has the `@cnt` variable which can be used to limit the loops. I would suggest a default input parameter for that).

The significant parts are the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SearchSRC(@html AS NVarChar(max))
RETURNS @SRC Table
(
  cnt     int,
  cstart   int,
  cend     int,
  src     NVarChar(250)
)
as
BEGIN

  declare @lcase NVarchar(max),
          @start int,
          @end int,
          @cnt int = 0

  select @lcase = lower(@html)

  select @start = CharIndex('src="', @lcase, 1) + 5
  select @end = charIndex('"', @lcase, @start)

  --insert into @SRC
  --select @cnt, @start, @end, @lcase

  -- use 5 start for start because we add 5 manually
  while @cnt < 10 and @start > 5 and @end > @start
  begin
    select @cnt = @cnt + 1

    insert into @SRC
    select @cnt, @start, @end, SubString(@html, @start, @end - @start)

    select @start = CharIndex('src="', @lcase, @end + 1) + 5
    select @end = CharIndex('"', @lcase, @start)

  end

  return
END
```

which is called as part of your query:

```
select id, crapp.src
from Posts
     cross apply SearchSRC(PostHTML) as crapp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SELECT 'SRC="' + LEFT(RIGHT(PostHTML, LEN(PostHTML) - CHARINDEX('src="', PostHTML) - 4), CHARINDEX('"', RIGHT(PostHTML, LEN(PostHTML) - CHARINDEX('src="', PostHTML) - 4 - 1))) + '"'
FROM post
```

**Output**

```
src="hello-world.jpg"
src="bowtie.gif"
src="smiley.gif"
SRC="FOO.GIF"
SRC="BAR.GIF"
SRC="INTERNET-CIRCA-1997.GIF"
```

Comment: This only returns the first occurrence in each row. Also, since not every row has images in it (I failed to mention this) I get some odd results like `><FONT FACE=`.

Answer (score 0):

here is your answer with using CTE if you're using 2008 and above:

`create table #objids_table (
        PostId int, 
        PostHTML    nvarchar(max)   null
        )`

insert all the values one by one

`;with T(PostHTML, starts, pos) as (
    select PostHTML, 1, charindex('src', PostHTML) from #objids_table
    union all
    select PostHTML, cast(pos + 1 as int), charindex('src', PostHTML, pos + 1)
    from T
    where pos > 0
)
select 
     substring(PostHTML, starts -1, charindex('"', PostHTML, starts + 4) - (starts - 2)) as img
from T
where starts <> 1
order by PostHTML, starts`

you can take a look at similar answers here:
[SQL Server - find nth occurrence in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726111/sql-server-find-nth-occurrence-in-a-string)

Comment: Note the question specifically was tagged with SQL Server 2005.