# SSRS SQL Serve - Extracting middle information from string

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I am working in SSRS SQL Server

I have several different strings and I want to extract information.

Examples:
 /features/all_tests/access/login.feature 
/features/all_tests/display/reactions_page/reaction_results_display.feature

I want to remove everything from the third ‘/’ and before and everything  after the last /

Results would be: 
access
display/reactions_page

I have used below to get the last portion
    ,REVERSE(left(REVERSE(tests.[path]), charindex('/',REVERSE(tests.   [path]))-1))

I have also used the below to extra some additional information

```
,substring(tests.[path],
CharIndex('/', (tests.[path]), 11)+1, 
(CharIndex('/',((substring(tests.[path], 
CharIndex('/', (tests.[path]), 12)+1, 77))),1)-1))
```

I can do everything around it but can’t get it to combine

Answer (score 0):

You may want to refer on this posts?

[SQL Server - find nth occurrence in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726111/sql-server-find-nth-occurrence-in-a-string)

It should answer your question.
Find the position and work with your concatenation.