# SQL Server : select text between 3rd and 4th occurrence of '.'

Tags: sql-server, substring, sql-server-2014

I use SQL Server 2014.

I have string like this:

```
A.U.TCZ.160001.AC
```

I need to get substring between 3rd and 4th occurrence of `.`, so in this example I should get `160001`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Declare @text varchar(100) = 'A.U.TCZ.160001.AC'

Declare @3rd int
Declare @4th int

Select @3rd = charindex('.',@text,charindex('.',@text,charindex('.',@text)+1)+1)
Select @4th = charindex('.',@text,@3rd+1)
Select Substring(@text, @3rd+1, @4th-@3rd-1)
```

More generic way how to do it you may find in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726111/sql-server-find-nth-occurrence-in-a-string)