# Sql server 2016 split after 5th comma

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016-express

I need to split the following string

```
10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29
```

to

```
10, 11, 12, 13, 14
15, 16, 17, 18, 19
20, 21, 22, 23, 24
25, 26, 27, 28, 29
```

Comment: will it always be  this format? two numbers then a comma then a space?

Comment: no it may be any string

Comment: So you want to take a delimited string and split it into multiple delimited strings? Using delimited string in the first place is a poor design choice. This just screams of things gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create function dbo.SplitString (@string varchar(max), @delimiter char(1), @Occurence int)
returns @t table
(
    String varchar(max)
)
as

begin
declare @i int = 0
    , @k int = 1
    , @j int = 0
    , @str varchar(max);

if right(@string, 1) <> ','
    set @string = @string + ',';

while CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @i + 1) > 0
begin
    set @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @i + 1);
    set @j = @j + 1;

    if @j = @Occurence or CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @i + 1) = 0
    begin
        insert into @t (String)
        select SUBSTRING (@string, @k, @i - @k);

        set @k = @i + 1;
        set @j = 0;
    end


end

return;

end

select *
from dbo.SplitString ('10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29', ',', 5);
```

Comment: Of all the splitters out there this is the absolute worst for performance. It is a multi-statement table valued function using loops inside. Here are several options that are MUCH better. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings Since we are wanting a specific position within the results I would prefer a different splitter. The one from Jeff Moden. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ It has the advantage of returning the position that none of the splitters do.

Comment: If we split into 6, the last two value is not showing

Comment: @ramkumar added functionality for Occurence = 6 or whatewer

Comment: @SeanLange, I absolutely agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

There are similar answers to this - try the following link: [SQL Server - find nth occurrence in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726111/sql-server-find-nth-occurrence-in-a-string)

What you're looking to do is find the Nth occurrence of a substring. I believe that I used the accepted answer in the aforementioned link to solve this when I had this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which is not so great but its still in set operation instead of loop as below:

```
Declare @str varchar(100) = '10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25'

;With cte as
    (
    select RowN = Row_Number() over (order by (SELECT NULL)), *, SplitValue= Case When (Row_Number() over (order by (Select NULL)) % 5 = 0 ) then [Value]+ '$' else [Value] end 
    from string_Split(@str, ',')
    ) 
    Select * from string_split( Stuff((Select ', ' + SplitValue from cte for xml path('')),1,1,''), '$')
```