# How to get sub string till 2nd occurence of delimiter

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to get sub string till 2nd occurence of delimiter, but some how its not working. I followed several stackoverflow links:

[SQL Server - find nth occurrence in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726111/sql-server-find-nth-occurrence-in-a-string)

Here is the column in my database:

```
this+is+my
never+ending+movie
hello
```

Required output

```
this+is
never+ending
hello
```

I tried:

```
charindex('+', col1, (charindex('+', col1, 1))+1)
```

> Error: SQL Error [500310] [42883]: Amazon Invalid operation: function charindex("unknown", character varying, integer) does not exist;

I am using Amzaon Redshift database and Dbeaver to connect.

Comment: Part of your problem is that you're trying to apply a SQL Server solution to a Redshift problem, and the two databases implement `CHARINDEX` differently, as indicated in the error message. The Redshift version does not include the third parameter, which the SQL Server code is trying to increment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SPLIT_PART](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/SPLIT_PART.html)

```
select split_part(col1,'+',1) || '+' || split_part(col1,'+',2) as string_value
from table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `left` with `Charindex`, try following

```
declare @S varchar(20) = 'this+problem+is+fixedby+Girish';
select left(@S, charindex('+', @S, charindex('+', @S)+1)-1) as Result;
```

here is [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4546ef47ccfc02ae9eab684273e2263d)

in your case:-

```
select left(columnname, charindex('+', columnname, charindex('+', @S)+1)-1) from your table as Result;
```