# Calculate the latest wave name

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

The following SQL retrieved the latest wave name based on the number suffix.

This is a wave name structure:**XXX_XXX_XXXXXXXXXX.XXXX_< incremented number >**

Example: **XXX_XXX_XXXXXXXXXX.XXXX_1 , XXX_XXX_XXXXXXXXXX.XXXX_2, XXX_XXX_XXXXXXXXXX.XXXX_3**

```
select  top 1 wave
from Outbound co WHERE Program = :Program
order by CAST(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(Wave, CHARINDEX('.', Wave)+ 1, len(wave)), PATINDEX('%[_]%', 
SUBSTRING(Wave, CHARINDEX('.', Wave)+ 1, len(wave)))+ 1, LEN(SUBSTRING(Wave, CHARINDEX('.', Wave)+ 1, len(wave)))) AS INT)  desc;
```

Lately, I notice that the wave name structure changed, there for the current SQL logic will not be applicable with the new format.

New format: **XXXX_XXXXXX_XXX.XXXXXXXXX_XXXX_XXXX__< incremented number > _< monthyear >**

Example: **XXXX_XXXXXX_XXX.XXXXXXXXX_XXXX_XXXX_81_042122, XXXX_XXXXXX_XXX.XXXXXXXXX_XXXX_XXXX_80_032122**

I would like to extend the current SQL logic to handle both scenarios in one SQL.

Any advice on how?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like Sybase or SQL Server. What database are you using? Sybase, SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, DB2, etc.

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Comment: Based on your sample inputs, it looks like the number of characters is consistent.  Why are you using `PATINDEX` and `CHARINDEX` rather than hard-coding the integers?  If the number of characters betwen the delimiters (`_` and `.`) varies, please post better sample data -- preferably with `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a little cleaner approach would be to apply a bit of JSON

```
Declare @YourTable table (wave varchar(100))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('XXX_XXX_XXXXXXXXXX.XXXX_1')
,('XXX_XXX_XXXXXXXXXX.XXXX_2')
,('XXXX_XXXXXX_XXX.XXXXXXXXX_XXXX_XXXX_81_042122')
,('XXXX_XXXXXX_XXX.XXXXXXXXX_XXXX_XXXX_80_032122')

Select Wave
      ,Pos1 = IsNull(JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[5]'),JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[3]'))
 From  @YourTable
 Cross Apply (values ('["'+replace(string_escape(wave,'json'),'_','","')+'"]') ) B(JS)
```

**Results**

[image]

Note:  Depending on your actual data, the `string_escape()` may not be necessary.

Comment: So you're splitting the value into a JSON array using `_` as the delimiter, then returning the value of element 5 or 3?  Nice!  Will that work in Oracle and Postgres, or is this solution limited to SQL Server?

Comment: @dougp I'd imagine.   I suspect the syntax would be a little different.

Answer (score 0):

I used common table expressions and incorporated the ["nth occurrence" code provided by Alex K.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726111/sql-server-find-nth-occurrence-in-a-string)

```
declare @Outbound table (
  Program varchar(50),
  wave varchar(50)
)

insert @Outbound
values 
  ('a', 'XXX_XXX_XXXXXXXXXX.XXXX_1')
, ('a', 'XXX_XXX_XXXXXXXXXX.XXXX_2')
, ('a', 'XXX_XXX_XXXXXXXXXX.XXXX_3')
, ('a', 'XXXX_XXXXXX_XXX.XXXXXXXXX_XXXX_XXXX_81_042122')
, ('a', 'XXXX_XXXXXX_XXX.XXXXXXXXX_XXXX_XXXX_80_032122')



;
with a as (
  select wave
  ,  SUBSTRING(
        Wave, 
        CHARINDEX('.', Wave) + 1, 
        len(wave)
      ) as expression
  , case
    when CHARINDEX('_', Wave) = 4
        then '1'
    when CHARINDEX('_', Wave) = 5
        then '2'
    else 'unknown'
    end as 'Wave Name Structure Version'
  from @Outbound co
  
  WHERE Program = 'a'
),
T(
    wave
  , expression
  , starts
  , pos
  , [Wave Name Structure Version]
) as (
  select wave
  , expression
  , 1
  , charindex('_', expression)
  , [Wave Name Structure Version] 
  from a
  union all
  select wave
  , expression
  , pos + 1
  , charindex('_', expression, pos + 1)
  , [Wave Name Structure Version]
  from t
  where pos > 0
), 
b as (
  select wave
  , [Wave Name Structure Version]
  , substring(expression, starts, case when pos > 0 then pos - starts else len(expression) end) WaveNumber
  , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by expression order by starts) as instance
  from T
)

select top 1 wave

from b

where instance = 
  case
    when [Wave Name Structure Version] = '1'
      then 2
    when [Wave Name Structure Version] = '2'
      then 4
  end

order by WaveNumber desc
```