# SQL query to find substring between repeating characters

Tags: sql, substring

I need a SQL query to get the substring between the second and third occurrence of the same character within a field.  In this case the repeating character is a hat ^.  As an example,

```
Party_Name      Address
IBM             IBM ^ IBM USA BR 1002 ^ 680 Langly Drive CA ^ NE ^ 0232232^ CC^
```

The ^ symbol appears multiple times in the address field, how do I retrieve "680 Langly Drive CA" only?

I have this so far

```
select Party_Name,
       substring(Address, charindex('^', Address....)
from table_name
```

I am not sure what to do next

Comment: Please update the tags of the question with the RDBMS you are using using (microsoft sql server, mysql, postgres, oracle, etc)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalent of explode() to work with strings in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928599/equivalent-of-explode-to-work-with-strings-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Considering you wanted to extract the string between 2nd and 3rd symbol only.

```
SELECT Party_Name ,SUBSTRING([Address2],1,CHARINDEX('^',[Address2])-1)
FROM 
    (
      SELECT Party_Name, SUBSTRING([Address1],charindex('^', 
             [Address1])+1,LEN([Address1])-CHARINDEX('^',[Address1] )) AS [Address2]
      FROM (    
                SELECT
                Party_Name,
                SUBSTRING([Address],CHARINDEX('^',[Address])+1,LEN([Address])-charindex('^',[Address] )) AS [Address1]
                FROM Table_Name
            )Ad1
    )Ad2
```

Answer (score -1):

try something like substring in substring, as the guy did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726111/sql-server-find-nth-occurrence-in-a-string)