# Replace everything after the second comma by "et al"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to parse some text (authors names) to replace everything after the second comma when there is too many authors for a specific book.

Example :

```
Michel Galarneau, Jean Valjean, Michel Tremblay, Martin St-Louis
```

Will be after string manipulation :

```
Michel Galarneau, Jean Valjean, et al.
```

So fat, I am able to capture the part I want to substitute, but I'm not sure it's the way to go...

```
(?:[^,]*,\s*){2}(.*)
```

This select the group "Marc St-Pierre, Yvon Sabon" that I want to replace with "et al.".

Thanks for any help !

Comment: What language/framework/application are you using to apply the regex?

Comment: It is in a SQL select.

Comment: What dialect? MySQL? T-SQL? PostgreSQL?

Comment: Sorry, it's a MS SQL Server database

Comment: Trying to do this in a SQL select in MSSQL Management Studio.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support RegEx natively. There are implementations of CLR to handle this, but they aren't even applicable depending on your platform. Is this on-prem SQL Server, Azure SQL Database, or Managed Instance? What is `@@VERSION`? There are potentially ways to do this with `OPENJSON` or `STRING_SPLIT`/`STRING_AGG` but they'll be version-dependent.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726111/sql-server-find-nth-occurrence-in-a-string, to find second comma. I.e. no regex needed.

Comment: I just managed to do it, not with regex...

With a CASE and Substring function

extract of the SQL Statement : 
,case when ta.NbAuteurID>2 then concat(substring(t2.PrenomNom,1,charindex(',',t2.PrenomNom,charindex(',',t2.PrenomNom)+1)-1),' et al.') else (case when t2.PrenomNom is null then 'Collectif' else t2.PrenomNom end) end AuteurVeriferCollectif

Answer (score 1):

Just another option using a bit of `JSON` and `concat()`  which treats `NULLs` as empty strings.

Note that if two or less, `no et al` presented.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(150))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('Michel Galarneau, Jean Valjean, Michel Tremblay, Martin St-Louis'),
 ('Author 1of2, Author 2of2'),
 ('Author 1of1')
 
Select A.SomeCol
      ,NewVal = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[0]')
                + concat('',', '+JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[1]'))
                + concat('',left(JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[2]'),0)+', et al')
From @YourTable A
Cross Apply (values ('["'+replace(string_escape([SomeCol],'json'),',','","')+'"]') ) B(JS)
```

**Results**

```
SomeCol                                                             NewVal
Michel Galarneau, Jean Valjean, Michel Tremblay, Martin St-Louis    Michel Galarneau,  Jean Valjean, et al
Author 1of2, Author 2of2                                            Author 1of2,  Author 2of2
Author 1of1                                                         Author 1of1
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to locate the position of the second comma and then use string functions to extract and concatenate the necessary parts of the string, I Hope this works.

```
DECLARE @InputString NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Michel Galarneau, Jean Valjean, Michel Tremblay, Martin St-Louis';

WITH CommaPositions AS (
    SELECT 
        CHARINDEX(',', @InputString) AS FirstCommaPos,
        CHARINDEX(',', @InputString, CHARINDEX(',', @InputString) + 1) AS SecondCommaPos
)
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN SecondCommaPos > 0 THEN 
            LEFT(@InputString, SecondCommaPos) + ' et al.' 
        ELSE 
            @InputString 
    END AS ModifiedString
FROM CommaPositions;
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do this with simple string functions in SQL Server:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufnTruncateAuthorList(@AuthorList varchar)
RETURNS varchar
AS
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @FirstComma int, @SecondComma int, @Result varchar;

    -- locate offset of the first comma
    SET @FirstComma = CHARINDEX(',', @AuthorList);
    -- locate offset of the second comma
    SET @SecondComma = CHARINDEX(',', @AuthorList, @FirstComma + 1);

    -- substring + concat only if more than one comma found
    IF @FirstComma = 0 OR @SecondComma = 0
        SET @Result = @AuthorList;
    ELSE
        SET @Result = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@AuthorList, 0, @SecondComma), ', et al.');
    RETURN @Result;
  END
```

Then you can do:

```
SELECT dbo.ufnTruncateAuthorList('Michel Galarneau, Jean Valjean, Michel Tremblay, Martin St-Louis')
```

Comment: Wasn't me, and I [doubt you'll get an explanation anyway](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C1772.4838). But I can see at least two major problems with your solution. Scalar functions are notoriously slow and don't scale; inline table-valued function would be much better. And you have multiple references to `varchar` with no length ... a [classic bad habit](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). You should try your function!

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks, that's at least helpful :)